# Python: the elements disappear while parsing

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I had a problem while parsing a website.

HTML on the website:

```
<div id="service">
      <div class="title">category</div>
      <div class="itemFrame" id="maintainFrame">
        <div class="col" style="display: inline-block;">
          <label>
            <div class="box fill" rel="1"></div>
            apple </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="display: none;">
          <label>
            <div class="box" rel="2"></div>
            banana </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

if "display: inline-block;" or div class="box fill", I will give it a value as Y, if not, I will give a F.

Code:

```
for num5 in soup.find_all(attrs={'id':'maintainFrame'}):
    print(num5)
```

it prints:

```
<div class="itemFrame" id="maintainFrame">
<div class="col">
<label>
<div class="box" rel="1"></div>
            apple </label>
</div>
<div class="col">
<label>
<div class="box" rel="2"></div>
            banana </label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know why they both show its class="box" and cannot see "style" in this. Because of this, I could not do the rest to distinguish it as Y or F.

The result I expected:

```
Y  #apple
F  #banana
```

Comment: What version of beautifulsoup are you using? This doesn't happen on `4.6.3`

Comment: Styles and additional class names might be assigned dynamically while page rendering, so this might not be reflected in page source

Comment: @declension mine is 4.6.0

Comment: Then yes - agree with @Andersson, sounds like the DOM is not the same as that downloaded HTML, i.e. JavaScript is being used. (or that User Agent sniffing means your browser is being sent a different version). Perhaps you should print out or save to disk the HTML you're getting in BS4 before parsing.

Comment: @declension but what if there are thousands of pages?

Comment: Well, just print the first few lines maybe. This is just to investigate what's happening. I tried your sample HTML (as a string) with `4.6.3` and it parsed and printed as you were hoping.

If it _is_ what we think (different HTML in the browser), then yes there's another problem to solve - but BS might not be your answer any more - perhaps try Selenium or other browser-based solutions.

Comment: Why don't you post a url?